# takeWhile, lambdas, and pattern matching

Tags: list, haskell

I'm pretty new to Haskell and still trying to learn the ropes. My problem is this:
I am trying to take all of the numbers which when added to the number after it in a list is less than a certain number. In a more formal sense, how can I use sublists of my list as arguments for my filtering boolean function?
For example: we have the list [a0,a1,a2,...], how can I take from the list while a_n + a_(n+1) < c (where c is just some number)?

Ultimately I am going to be using this to create a sequence of root approximations of a function. Currently I have an infinite list of approximations (since I don't know where to stop yet) and I would like to take all of the approximations up until an approximation that has some tolerable error. The error of the approximation p_n is given as a function of p_n, p_(n-1), p_(n-2). Lets call this function f. So ideally I would like to keep taking elements from the list while
f(p_(n),p_(n-1),p_(n-2)) > error.

Comment: Does it have to hold for the last element in the list?

Comment: In the current application I'm using it for no, since the list is infinite.

Comment: If the list is infinite, are the elements in the list ordered?

Comment: Not necessarily, the list is a sequence of root approximations and so the approximations may start to oscillate around the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of the function you want to write looks like this

```
takeLessThan :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> [a] -> [a]
takeLessThan bound xs = ...
```

You can extract each pair of the list by zipping the list with the tail of itself.

```
pairs :: [b] -> [(b, b)]
pairs xs = zip xs (tail xs)
```

So the pairs of the list `[1,2,3,4,5]` will give you a tuple of (a<sub>n</sub>, a<sub>n+1</sub>).

```
[(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,5)]
```

From there you can use the `filter` function from the Prelude to select the elements you want based on the function `(a -> Bool)`.

```
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: hmm I understand what you're suggesting and it makes sense. How can this be generalized to a tuple with n elements though since zip only works with two elements? Also what if the list is infinite? I'm assuming that we would have to use takeWhile if we are working with an infinite list correct?

Comment: If the list is infinite and unordered we can't write down an implementation since you'll never know if the (n+1)th element holds for your property. You could have an infinite sequence of zeros as the tail for instance which would never terminate. Unless of course you want to work with resulting infinite list then use `takeWhile`.

Answer (score 1):

I think its easier to break down your problem into multiple steps intead of trying to solve it all at once with a super smart filtering function.

1. Start with a list [a0 ... an]
2. Turn it into a list of pairs [ (a0, a1) ... (a_n-1, an) ] with `zip`
3. Filter the interesting pairs with `takeWhile` (or `filter`, depending on what you want to do).
4. Turn the list of good pairs back into a list with just the first numbers using `map`

Don't worry about performance or about generating wasteful intermediate lists. Everything should be efficiently created on demand due to the lazy evaluation.

Comment: How would I go about breaking the list up into tuples of three elements instead of two? Such as [(a0,a1,a2),(a1,a2,a3),...]

Comment: Nvm, just discovered zip3

Comment: @ra91: Next time you are looking for a function, check out Hoogle. It lets you find functions given the type signature: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=[a]+-%3E+[b]+-%3E+[c]+-%3E+[%28a%2Cb%2Cc%29]

Comment: will do! and thanks for the help. I was finally able to get it to work. Even though this works, is there a cleaner way of doing it? This feels a bit hacky for haskell.

Comment: @ra91: Using zip and doing list processing over multiple steps is perfectly idiomatic Haskell. I don't think you can get much cleaner than this.